# Declaring Pydantic Model "TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable"

Tags: python, list, fastapi, pydantic

I'm using FastAPI to build a data API. I want the clients to post 2 lists of 24 floats that later I will save into a database.

When I try to create the Pydantic model:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Prices(BaseModel):
    buying_price: list(float)=[]
    selling_price: list(float)=[]
```

I get the following error:

```
File "c:/Users/Amin y Lubna/FastAPI-InfluxDB/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Prices(BaseModel):
File "c:/Users/Amin y Lubna/FastAPI-InfluxDB/test.py", line 4, in Prices
    buying_price: list(float)=[]
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Even though  the error is self-explanatory, I don't understand it.

Then, looking at the documentation I found the following way:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List

class Prices(BaseModel):
    buying_price: List(float)=[]
    selling_price: List(float)=[]
```

But I got the following error.

```
File "c:/Users/Amin y Lubna/FastAPI-InfluxDB/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Prices(BaseModel):
File "c:/Users/Amin y Lubna/FastAPI-InfluxDB/test.py", line 5, in Prices
    buying_price: List(float)=[]
File "C:\Users\Amin y Lubna\anaconda3\lib\typing.py", line 727, in __call__
    raise TypeError(f"Type {self._name} cannot be instantiated; "
TypeError: Type List cannot be instantiated; use list() instead
```

I've been struggling with the error a couple days and I'm not able to find a solution to the issues.

Comment: You mean `list[float]`, or in older version of Python, `List[float]`. Note the `[]`. `()` is attempting to call `list` as a function, which will attempt to coerce `float` (a type) into a list; thus the error.

Comment: Thank you!!! Didn't realize about the brackets.

Comment: `()` typically means "call as a function". `[]` means either "index the sequence", or if it's a type, "make a specialized version of a generic type". You mean the last of the three.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `list[float]`, not `list(float)`